# Uniform continuity of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-continuity

I want to confirm the result   that  $f(x)$  is uniform  continous   on $I$  iff $| f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$   for each $x,y \in I$ .
Is it true if $I$ is closed ? Or for every interval ?

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Take $f(x)=2x$, for instance, on any interval.